# VLOOKUP with multiple return values Libre Office VB

Tags: vbscript, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I am looking for a *VLOOKUP* function that returns multiple values in the cell. Sometimes the column you are searching contains more than once the value.

For instance I have a list of products to import in Woocommerce, those products have variables and variations. I want to fill attributes cells of Variable with all its variation's attributes as a list. Then I search for ID in parent column and return the list of attributes.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I found.

```
'E2 = searchCell = SKU
'3 = columNumWhereToSearch = Parent
'6 = columnNumWhatToGet = Attribute

Function MULTIPLE_VLOOKUP(searchCell, columNumWhereToSearch, columnNumWhatToGet) As String
    Dim Doc As Object
    Dim Sheet As Object
    Dim Cell As Object   
     
    Doc = ThisComponent
    Sheet = Doc.Sheets(0)

    Dim AttributeListString As String
    AttributeListString = ""
    
    'Set the number of row to search
    For I = 1 To 150
        CellToSearch = Sheet.getCellByPosition(columNumWhereToSearch, I)
        If CellToSearch.String = searchCell then
            CellToGetAndReturn = Sheet.getCellByPosition(columnNumWhatToGet, I).String
            If Len(CellToGetAndReturn) > 0 And CellToGetAndReturn <> "Err:522" And CellToGetAndReturn <> "Err:508" And CellToGetAndReturn <> "#NAME?"  And CellToGetAndReturn <> "#NULL!" And CellToGetAndReturn <> "#VALUE!" And CellToGetAndReturn <> "#REF!" then
                If Len(AttributeListString ) > 0 then
                    AttributeListString = AttributeListString + ","
                End If
                AttributeListString = AttributeListString + CellToGetAndReturn
            End If
        End If
    Next I
    multiple_vlookup = AttributeListString
End Function
```

Use it like `=MULTIPLE_VLOOKUP(E2;4;7)`

Comment: @73k04 No. It will not work. Not `Sub` but `Function`, not all errors are checked (Err: 508, #DIV/0!  etc.), end of code was skipped... I cannot find this answer useful, but I also consider it harmful - it misleads those who are looking for a solution to their problems. Please change your answer, complete it and I will withdraw my negative vote.

Comment: Hi @JohnSUN thank you for the feedback, I tried to correct it and I tested the code, it works on my side, let me know what you think.

Comment: Yes, much better that way, I called back my negative vote. This is still not an ideal solution (it works only on the first sheet of the spreadsheet, on other sheets it will give incorrect results; in the list of errors "#NAME?" Is named twice; getting values ​​from cells, not from array). I have not tested this code in work, but if you claim that it works for you, I will gladly believe it.

Comment: Hi, thank you again for your feedbacks I removed the extra "#NAME?" in error code checking. For the second sheet, I honestly don't know, I just needed first sheet and wanted to share my code if someone needs it...